# How to hide a button until a selection is made in the dropdown in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, button, hide, show

I have three dropdowns on the page. Upon selecting a value in the first dropdown, the other two dropdowns gets populated. Now, I want to have a button appear upon making a selection in either second or third dropdown.

Here's what I have tried:

dropdowns:

```
<form class="cmxform" action ='functions/processform.php' id="Form1" method="post">
           <legend> Faculty Transaction Form</legend>
            <label for="addname">Please Select School</label>
           <select class="form-control" name="school" id="school">
                <?php
                $nameslist = $getschool->getSchool();
                oci_execute($nameslist, OCI_DEFAULT);
                while ($row = oci_fetch_array($nameslist, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $row['SCHOOLPROPERNAME'] . '">' . $row['SCHOOLPROPERNAME']. '</option>';
                }
                ?>
           </select>
            <label for="names">Please Select Name</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="names" id="names1234">
               <option value='0' >Select Name</option>

        </select>
            <label for="names">Recall FTF in progress</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="ftf" id="ftf">
               <option value='0' >Select Name</option>

        </select>
            <p>Paid/Unpaid/Terminated:</p>
            <div>
            <input type="radio" id="paid" name="paid" value="paid" >
            <label for="paid">Paid</label>
            </div>
            <div>
            <input type="radio" id="unpaid" name="unpaid" value="unpaid" >
            <label for="unpaid">Un-Paid</label>
            </div>
            <div>
            <input type="radio" id="terminated" name="terminated" value="terminated" >
            <label for="terminated">Terminated</label>
            </div>
        </form>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="recallFTF"  value="Recall FTF"  />

    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#names1234').change(function() {
  $('#recallFTF').show();
  if ($('#names1234').val() === '') {
    $('#recallFTF').show();
  } else {
      $('#recallFTF').hide();
  }
});

 });
```

The above code works the opposite. With that, there's always the button which disappears on selection made in the second dropdown. I have followed a few similar questions here but none of them was able to answer my question. Please let me know if you want to see more code. I have only posted the relevant part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will show the button when either of the latter select boxes are not empty.

With your code, you checked if the value was `''` but you set the option value to `0` so it was not `''`. I've added a few `<option>` to help you with the understanding of what I mean. I have also hidden the button at the start of the jQuery since you only want it to show when there is a full form to submit.

You'll notice the grouping of the selectors (`$('#names1234, #ftf')`). This allows you to check against both of the select boxes at the same time without having to duplicate code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#recallFTF').hide();
  $('#names1234, #ftf').change(function() {
    $('#recallFTF').show();
    if ($('#names1234').val() !== '' || $('#ftf').val() !== '') {
      $('#recallFTF').show();
    } else {
      $('#recallFTF').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="cmxform" action='functions/processform.php' id="Form1" method="post">
  <legend> Faculty Transaction Form</legend>
  <label for="addname">Please Select School</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="school" id="school">
    <?php
                $nameslist = $getschool->getSchool();
                oci_execute($nameslist, OCI_DEFAULT);
                while ($row = oci_fetch_array($nameslist, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $row['SCHOOLPROPERNAME'] . '">' . $row['SCHOOLPROPERNAME']. '</option>';
                }
                ?>
  </select>
  <label for="names">Please Select Name</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="names" id="names1234">
    <option value=''>Select Name</option>
    <option value='0'>0</option>
    <option value='1'>1</option>

  </select>
  <label for="names">Recall FTF in progress</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="ftf" id="ftf">
    <option value=''>Select Name</option>
    <option value='0'>0</option>
    <option value='1'>1</option>

  </select>
  <p>Paid/Unpaid/Terminated:</p>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="paid" name="paid" value="paid">
    <label for="paid">Paid</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="unpaid" name="unpaid" value="unpaid">
    <label for="unpaid">Un-Paid</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="terminated" name="terminated" value="terminated">
    <label for="terminated">Terminated</label>
  </div>
</form>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="recallFTF" value="Recall FTF" />

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Ashok OP stated "I want to have a button appear upon making a selection in either second or third dropdown".

Comment: @Ashok `||` is the `OR` operator so it would be either option, not both (what I believe you mean would be `AND` in this case)

Answer (score 1):

This code is works, you can change your values.

```
<div><div>
<form class="cmxform" action ='functions/processform.php' id="Form1" method="post">
       <legend> Faculty Transaction Form</legend>
        <label for="addname">Please Select School</label>
       <select class="form-control" name="school" id="school">
       <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
            <option value='0' >Select Name0</option>
       </select>
        <label for="names">Please Select Name</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="names" id="names1234">
      <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
           <option value='0' >Select Name1</option>
           <option value='1' >Select Name2</option>

    </select>
        <label for="names">Recall FTF in progress</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="ftf" id="ftf">
      <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
           <option value='0' >Select Name</option>

    </select>
        <p>Paid/Unpaid/Terminated:</p>
        <div>
        <input type="radio" id="paid" name="paid" value="paid" >
        <label for="paid">Paid</label>
        </div>
        <div>
        <input type="radio" id="unpaid" name="unpaid" value="unpaid" >
        <label for="unpaid">Un-Paid</label>
        </div>
        <div>
        <input type="radio" id="terminated" name="terminated" value="terminated" >
        <label for="terminated">Terminated</label>
        </div>
    </form>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="recallFTF"  value="Recall FTF"  />

    </div>
</div>       
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#recallFTF').hide();
    $('#names1234').on('change', function() {
        if (!$("#names1234 option:selected").length) {
        $('#recallFTF').hide();
        } else {
         $('#recallFTF').show();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks it works but I want that for the third dropdown also. If the selection has been made in either second or third dropdown, the button should appear then